# Wait-free queue from Boost.Atomic example crashes

Tags: c++, boost, concurrency, c++11, atomic

I was looking for C++ implementation of wait-free queue using atomics and found Boost.Atomic example:

```
template<typename T>
class waitfree_queue {
public:
  struct node {
    T data;
    node * next;
  };
  void push(const T &data)
  {
    node * n = new node;
    n->data = data;
    node * stale_head = head_.load(boost::memory_order_relaxed);
    do {
      n->next = stale_head;
    } while (!head_.compare_exchange_weak(stale_head, n, boost::memory_order_release));
  }

  node * pop_all(void)
  {
    T * last = pop_all_reverse(), * first = 0;
    while(last) {
      T * tmp = last;
      last = last->next;
      tmp->next = first;
      first = tmp;
    }
    return first;
  }

  waitfree_queue() : head_(0) {}

  // alternative interface if ordering is of no importance
  node * pop_all_reverse(void)
  {
    return head_.exchange(0, boost::memory_order_consume);
  }
private:
  boost::atomic<node *> head_;
};

int main() {
// pop elements
waitfree_queue<int>::node * x = q.pop_all()
while(x) {
  X * tmp = x;
  x = x->next;
  // process tmp->data, probably delete it afterwards
  delete tmp;
}

}
```

[Example at boost official site](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/atomic/usage_examples.html#boost_atomic.usage_examples.mp_queue)

I've replaced boost with std and compiled with MSVC 2012.
It crashes with next message in console:

```
Assertion failed: _Order2 != memory_order_release, file c:\program files (x86)\m
icrosoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xxatomic, line 742
```

When I compile original boost it runs w/a crash.

Is it bug in Boost.Atomic or in MSVC implementation of atomic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a bug in MSVC implementation. The assertion fails because `Order2` is `memory_order_release`. However, as noted [here](http://www.stdthread.co.uk/doc/headers/atomic/atomic/compare_exchange_weak.html) (which is the same as the C++ standard) (emphasis mine):

> The 3-parameter overload is equivalent to the 4-parameter overload
>   with success_order==order, and failure_order==order, except that if
>   order is std::memory_order_acq_rel, then failure_order is
>   std::memory_order_acquire, and **if order is std::memory_order_release
>   then failure_order is std::memory_order_relaxed**.

In other words, `Order2` *must be* `std::memory_order_relaxed` for the 4-parameter overload in your case because you passed `memory_order_release` as `order`. This is not the case in MSVC's implementation which is a bug. Please report it as a bug if possible.